# OpenCV polygon detection methods

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

So I have a digital form with fields like this:

[image]

The problem is that people fill these fields in many different ways: different colors

[image]

gradients and so on. So the only thing that remains consistent is the shape of the field.

How do I detect all such shapes and make sure that they are *filled*.
Tried template matching but it doesn't work consistently on images with gradients or with images of low contrast where thresholding doesn't help much, and now I'm stuck.

I use OpenCV 3.1 along with Python 2.7.

**EDIT:** Tried to do it this way. It seems to provide results that are much more convenient for further processing but I'm still confused about next step.

```
import cv2

base_img = cv2.imread("form_base.png", 0)
form_img = cv2.imread("test2.png", 0)
ret,thresh1 = cv2.threshold(base_img,244,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
ret,thresh2 = cv2.threshold(form_img,244,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

res = thresh1 - thresh2

cv2.imwrite("test_output.png", res)
```

[That's what I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/45FXT.png)

Comment: Can't you just the two images, and check for differences? Or check if your _arrows_ are filled with white or not? You don't need to detect polygons, just find connected components.

Comment: Background can vary in color as well, so checking if they are filled with white is pointless. And I don't quite understand what do you mean by 'connected components'.

Comment: 1) you should then post some image of filled and non filled forms, as well as _empty_ forms. 2) Regarding connected components, you should study a little about this, since they are quite important in image processing.

Comment: Tried to get a difference mask of empty and filled forms (added to the initial post) and it worked pretty well, thank you. But I still need to count those arrows, would appreciate any suggestions. Image processing (as well as graph theory) is Greek to me, just started learning :)

Comment: Start playing with `findContours` or `connectedComponents`. You'll be able to find (and count) the white blobs. Then just group them (it'll be useful if you have a fixed layout for the forms) and you can get your result.

Comment: Including the images to your source code might help us providing an answer ...

Answer (score 1):

The task is pretty easy if you do image segmentation with connectedComponents and then characterize the blobs found. This is one possible approach:

```
    import cv2
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

    img = cv2.imread('test2.png')
    # Convert image to grayscale and get threshold image or mask:
    g = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    th, im_th = cv2.threshold(g, 220, 250, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
    # Opening, just to have delimited edges and make sure to separate each component:
    kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT,(2,2))
    im_th2 = cv2.morphologyEx(im_th, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
    # Connected Components segmentation:
    maxLabels, labels = cv2.connectedComponents(im_th2)
    plt.imshow(labels)
```

[image: image segmented]

As you can see, those components *filled* will be bigger in size (number of pixels) than the ones *not filled*, so you can get the size of each component and see if is filled or not. For example: You can get the maximum value of blob sizes, and make a threshold, since, as observed, those not filled will have less than half the size of those filled:

```
   # Get size of blobs: First value is always "empty" space, 0 on the mask, so discard it 
   sizes = np.array([len(labels[labels==i]) for i in range(1,maxLabels)])
   # Threshold with minimum value:
   thSizes = np.max(sizes)/2
```

You can count the number of *filled* components or do other desired operations from here:

```
   n_blobs = len(sizes[sizes>thSizes])
   print('There are ' + str(n_blobs) + ' fields filled.')
   >>>There are 6 fields filled.
```